# How does the Google Doodle celebrating Robert Moog generate the sounds?

Tags: javascript

I'm inspecting today's [Google Doodle celebrating Robert Moog](http://www.google.com/doodles/robert-moogs-78th-birthday). It's all JavaScript it seems. I know how to play prefabricated sound wave files and generate sound files on-the-fly using JavaScript, but this seems to go way beyond that. How does this doodle generate the sound?

Comment: Are you asking for someone to sift through all the Javascript and figure this out?

Comment: I'm wondering if anyone could think of how they possibly could have done this (without peeking at the solution ;-)

Comment: @JimSoho - "Peeking at the solution" is kind of what makes web development interesting. If you want to know how someone did something, just look!

Comment: Also interested! Audio waveform generation and playback is possible in JS. Here are some projects I've seen before: 
https://github.com/gasman/jsmodplayer
https://github.com/gasman/jasmid

Comment: I do not see a reason to close this question. I am interested in this too. There may be people who know the answer or can provide hints and links. Why close??