# Webkit Audio API versus Flash/AS, re: implementation of google-moog doodle

Tags: javascript, flash, audio, webkit

I've just registered for a stackoverflow account, in order to re-post, and answer, a question that was previously closed - for, if you ask me, insufficient rationale.

Here is the (basic) question, as phrased to me by a colleague yesterday:
Did the Google Bob Moog birthday doodle use the w3c audio API recommendation, as currently only implemented in Chrome (and only on certain platforms).

This question grabbed me because I've been working with said API intensively recently.  Here is a jsfiddle (not my work) using the essential API calls: http://jsfiddle.net/also/6bM3w/

I think it's of tremendous interest, in general, how google deployed a realtime, sample-accurate (and, even, recordable), analogue of the modular audio-synthesis technology that Mr. Moog pioneered ... that is, especially of interest: how they deployed it /across/ browsers.

The answer is provided in this article: 
http://mashable.com/2012/05/23/googles-moog-doodle-the-inside-story/ 
-- in short: "Hurst [the author of the code in question] said Google recently added the Web Audio API to Google Chrome. It provides, he said, “Really high-quality, low-latency audio” in the browser, but not in all Web browsers. Outside of Chrome, the Moog Doodle turns into pure Flash.

... This is tremendously exciting and timely stuff.  And I'm sure the question was only closed with the best intentions, but, I'd say you jumped the gun.

The original, closed question, for reference: [How does the Google Doodle celebrating Robert Moog generate the sounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711631/how-does-the-google-doodle-celebrating-robert-moog-generate-the-sounds)